# Trying to show pictures from folder using while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to show pictures from folder using while loop. I'm using while loop to generate html img tags, it should generate not more than 5 img tags with filled src parameter, depending on how much files is in directory, but it generates two more img tags with empty src parameter.

My code is:

```
if (is_dir($directory)) {
   if ($dh = opendir($directory)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo '<img style="width:100px; height:100px" src="/resource/news_img/'.$Row['dimg'].'/'.$file.'">';
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

I can not understand why this happening. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readdir` will also list `.` and `..` paths (current and parent directory), you need to filter them out.

```
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        // ...
    }
}
```